# How to separate logs from syslog on microstack

Tags: openstack, logging

I have microstack up an d running.
I want to debug a problem, but all logs are in syslog, which is a pain, because its way too much data.
Openstack defaults every service to a different logfile, but it looks like microstack is not using the same policy.

Is there a way of changing that? If so, how do I do it?

Ubuntu server 18.04, no gui.

Thanks

Comment: It seems that at least some messages are logged to the journal, for example `journalctl -u snap.microstack.cinder-scheduler.service`. However, weirdly not all OpenStack components seem to be implemented as services on my Microstack installation; for example, I don't see `cinder-api`.

Comment: There is a service named `snap.microstack.cinder-uwsgi.service`, which might be Cinder's API service.